# earth ground for a pool at a divorced location

Tags: grounding, pool

i am putting a service to a deck area for a new pool and pump, there is an earth ground copper covered rod buried 10 feet which is 25 feet from the underground pipe i am splicing into for the pool power. can i splice the ground at that point essentially creating a 'y' between the subpanel in the garage and the breaker box i am installing at the pool and the earth ground in an effort to avoid rinning another 100 feet of solid copper ground wire from the pool breaker box all the way back to the earth ground rod. ty

Comment: Is the electrical feeder 3-wire or 4-wire?  Can we get a clearer description and/or photos?

Comment: i edited my post but did not hear back unless i dont know how to have the edit be seen by everyone. please advise

Comment: @jeffsparks -- is this going to be a permanently installed pool or a storable pool?  How many wires are in the pipe you are "splicing into"? And yes...it looks like your edit didn't "take"

Comment: 3 wires, no-shield stranded ground, 2 #6 cables neutral and load, easy to handle 30amps or less load

Comment: sorry, above ground to stay.

Comment: The edit did not stick.  It shows no edit except ThreePhaseEel adding tags.

Comment: What kind of pool? Above ground? Temporary how tall are the sides? Above ground pools have different requirements than In ground. After re reading I see above ground in comments. Size and type of motor ie 120v fed from GFCI plug on pump with a ~20’ cord.

Comment: 120v, gfci, plug on pump with its own gfci plug, 15ft cord. 42 inch side, sub panel in garage not bonded to neutral. ty for your response.

Comment: can not seem to get the edit to do anything but save!